# Gopy: how to quickly pass larger array from Go to Python

Tags: python, performance, go

I use [gopy](https://github.com/go-python/gopy) v0.31 for interacting between Go 1.13 and Python 3.7. I call an expensive go function from within a python interpreter and this go function returns an array: `[12]float64`.

The wrapped function call in gopy returns a `Array_12_float64` class. Converting data from this class to a python list via `list(returnedObj)` takes approx. 150us on my machine, 10x more than the call itself.

Do you know if there is a way to avoid the slow `Array_12_float64` wrapper class and return *a python list* directly or use some other workaround to get data faster? Thank you. This is driving me nuts :-D.

Comment: What happens if you wrap that Go function with another which would basically to `return that_array_argument[:]`—that is, would slice the array. Arrays in Go have fixed size, encoded in their types, while slices have dynamic storage—just like Python lists; so that `gopy` thing might have special treatment for slice which _might_ bring you the speedup you need.

Comment: Another possible approach is to make your Go package export a sensible C API via the stock Go feature [`cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) and then hand-craft a CPython extension module around that C-callable library. This way you will have almost precise control about bit twiddling when calling between the both sides. But it requires deep knowledge of CPython, C and `cgo`.

Comment: thank you @kostix for your suggestions. I would like to continue using gopy. it works for me besides this problem. I expose a lot of code from Go to Python using gopy.